# make Button/Widget appear for X days or specific period from Date_X to Date_Z

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add (FloatingActionButton) appear for X days or a specific period from Date_X to Date_Z

I think it should be something like this

```
if ((DateTime.now =< DateTime.utc(2021,4,1)) && (DateTime.now => DateTime.utc(2021,5,1))){FloatingActionButton()}
```

I know there is a DateTimeRange class in flutter but I couldn't make it work.

So could anyone help with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, declare four variable

```
  bool _isStaisfied = false;
  DateTime _now = new DateTime.now();
  DateTime _startRange; // asign your Date;
  DateTime _endRange; // asign your Date;
```

and in initstate(), compare them,and assign _isSatisfied value based upon them,

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("helllo ");
    if (_now.isAfter(_startRange) && _now.isBefore(_endRange)) { // apply condition as you requirement
      setState(() {
      _isStaisfied = true;
    });
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

and apply Condition in scaffold

```
floatingActionButton: _isStaisfied ?  FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: null,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ) : null,
```

though this is not best practice, but will save the day!

Comment: Thanks so much for your concern, I add the code & assigned dates, It made the  FloatingActionButton be hidden but when I make starting date 4 April it's not showing the button this is the dates ` DateTime _startRange = DateTime(2021, 4, 3);
  DateTime _endRange = DateTime(2021, 5, 11); `

Comment: I create a new flutter project to check the code but the same result could you check the  [full code from here](https://codepad.site/view/5u45341k)

Comment: @HAmr , I mentioned to change the condition as your requirement, As from your given code, I created a new file https://codepad.site/pad/5u45341k  , and I tested it, and working perfectly in my end, if you check the code of mine, you can see that  I printed the value of _isStaisfied , you can check that too.
let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, the problem was `if (_startRange.isAfter(_now) && _endRange.isBefore(_now))` as my suggested edit `if (_now.isAfter(_startRange) && _now.isBefore(_endRange))` , And Voala :) it's now working great, Again thanks my friend for your solution it saved my day :).

Comment: Glad to hear that ^_^